# Scala Polymorphic Function That Would Compile But Would Not Run As Expected

Tags: scala, parametric-polymorphism

Given following two Scala functions, both compiles as expected.

```
scala> def toList[A](a: A) = List(a)
toList: [A](a: A)List[A]

scala> def foo[A](f: A => List[A], b: A) = f(b)
foo: [A](f: A => List[A], b: A)List[A]
```

Yet, when you run it, it gave following error message:

```
scala> foo(toList, 12)
<console>:14: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Nothing => List[Nothing]
 required: Int => List[Int]
       foo(toList, 12)
```

Why does Scala think `toList` function is of `Nothing => List[Nothing]` instead of `Int => List[Int]`?

Comment: In cases like this the inference engine needs a little help: `foo[Int](toList, 34)` or `foo(toList[Int], 34)`

Answer (score 1):

According how `foo` is defined, `foo(12, toList)` is wrong in passing the arguments. Correct way is `foo(toList, 12)`

> > Why does Scala think toList function is of Nothing => List[Nothing] instead of Int => List[Int]?

`12` is of `Int` type and since `foo` is

```
def foo[A](f: A => List[A], b: A) = f(b)
```

its expecting `A` type which is `Int` for the `toList` function as well.

If you call `foo` as `foo(toList, 12D)` we get following error

```
<console>:22: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Nothing => List[Nothing]
 required: Double => List[Double]
       foo(toList, 12D)
```

Its because `12D` is `Double type` and `toList` is expected to be of `Double` too.

So the correct way would be

```
foo(toList[Any], 12)
```

Answer (score 1):

The Scala compiler will try to infer the type parameters of the method, it will look to the parameters defined int he first parenthesis and try to extract the type from them, if it can not it will pick the next parameter group to infer the type, and so on...

The best way to define that function is like this

```
def foo[A](b: A)(f: A => List[A]) = f(b)
```

Giving the parameters in this order will allow you to avoid the need of giving some hint to the compliler. You can call this function like this:

```
foo(2.0d)(toList)
```

And you will get a List[Double]

If you keep the other order you will need to give a hint to the compiler in order to figure out the type parameter A

```
foo(toList[Double], 2.0d)
```